# How to search teradata column descriptions

Tags: teradata

Is there a way to search for a word, a string, in teradata column descriptions?

For example, if there is a column in some table named MKT, and its description says "Marketing". Is there a way of searching for "Marketing" so that this description will show up?

Answer (score 2):

When *Description* means the column *Comment*, you can easily query dbc.ColumnsV:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbc.ColumnsV
WHERE CommentString LIKE '%marketing%'
```